# Is it possible to make an interactive fully homomorphic encrypted (Turing) machine?

Tags: encryption

Using FHE schemes it is possible to perform NAND operations on encrypted data without knowing the decryption key.

If I were to implement something like a universal turing machine using only NAND gates, the encrypted input could encode a program that is running without me knowing anything about its internal state.

Since I can construct 0 and 1 from unknown ciphertexts using NAND gates, I can extend the machine to also have a phase where the FHE operator can give an input to the internal program.

Now my question is, is there any way for the internal program to give any information to the outside without requiring the operator to know the decryption key? Or can FHE schemes be extended to allow for that kind of behavior so a two-way interactive encrypted virtual machine would become possible?

Comment: By "touring machine" you mean "Turing machine", right?

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.

Comment: Would is be possible yes, would it be easy not so much.  You would need to be able to provide the key/iv start or else have this fixed for every run (or have some way to stay in sync between endpoints).  You can even do this mechanically (that's how enigma, lorenz and various other cipher machines worked.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming question.

Comment: The programming related part is how to adapt an existing FHE library to allow for two-way communication, but that is just implicit from the question above and not related to a specific FHE library, but rather related their common properties.